# how to store custom objects in NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutabledictionary, nsobject

I'm new to iOS. I have a class derived from `NSObject` and I want to store its reference into `NSMutableDictionary`. How can I?
e.g.

```
    @interface CustomClass : NSObject
    {
    }
```

I want to store reference (*customClass) of this CustomClass into `NSMutableDictionary`.
Please give me the simple way to store and retrieve it.

Comment: it's very simple.Please search for the solution first if you don't get then ask here.

Comment: As long as it is an NSOject subclass, you can add it as you would any other. The keys are usually best left as strings though.

Answer (score 4):

For that purpose, you need to use NSKeyedArchiver and NSCoder classes, as following:

In your CustomClass.m file, implement the following two encoding and decoding methods :

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    // encoding properties 
    [encoder encodeObject:self.property1 forKey:@"property1"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.property2 forKey:@"property2"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if((self = [super init])) {
        // decoding properties 
        self.property1 = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"property1"];
        self.property2 = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"property2"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Use it for setting and getting object like this:

```
 // For setting custom class objects on dictionary

 CustomClass * object = /*..initialisation....*/;
 NSData *encodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:object];
 [dictionary setObject:encodedObject forKey:key];

 // For getting custom class objects from dictionary

 NSData *encodedObject = [dictionary objectForKey:key];
 CustomClass * object = (CustomClass *)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:encodedObject];
```

**UPDATE:**
Better way is to use simple and easy to use third party library: RMMapper - https://github.com/roomorama/RMMapper

Answer (score 0):

When storing an object in a `NSMutableDictionary` you are storing a reference (pointer) to the object, not the object itself. So you don't need to treat objects of your `CustomClass` any differently to standard objects.

All the following will work:

```
    CustomClass *customObject;

    NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:customObject, @"key", nil];
    [mutableDictionary setObject:customObject forKey:@"key"];
    CustomClass *retrievedObject = [mutableDictionary objectForKey:@"key"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 NSMutableDictionary *obect = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:CustomObject forKeys:@"Customobjectkey"];
```

you can get the object with this key "**Customobjectkey**" and type cast that object as per the class.

Answer (score 0):

A [`NSMutableDictionary`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is a `NSDictionary` in which you can dynamically add and remove pairs in the for of value-key.

You simply have to specify some key value to pair it when you add a custom object in it (ie a `NSString`).

```
 CustomClass * myObj = ... //declared and initialized obj

 NSMutableDictionary * myDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; //declared and initialized mutable dictionary

 [myDict setObject:myObj forKey:@"first"]; //assigning a string key to the object

 NSLog(@"My first object was %@", [myDict objectForKey:@"first"]); //retrieving the object using its key. It will print its reference

 CustomClass * anotherObj = (CustomClass *)[myDict objectForKey:@"first"]; //retrieving it and assigning to another reference obj. It returns a NSObject, you have to cast it

 [myDict removeObjectForKey:@"first"]; //removing the pair obj-key
 NSLog(@"My first object was %@", [myDict objectForKey:@"first"]); //cannot find it anymore
```

Here is a little [tutorial with NSDictionaries](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000010.php).

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to create a NSMutableDictionary iVar in a UIViewController class called ViewController.

ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *mutDict;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CustomClass.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize mutDict=_mutDict;

-(void)viewDidLoad{
 [super viewDidLoad];
 CustomClass *cc1=[[CustomClass alloc] init];
 CustomClass *cc2=[[CustomClass alloc] init];
 self.mutDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: cc1, @"key1", cc2, @"key2", nil];
}

@end
```

Please note that I did not do any memory management in this example (assuming ARC), and I have not tested this code.

Answer (score -1):

```
//store
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:customClass forKey:@"myCustomClass"];

//retrieve
CustomClass *c = (CustomClass*)[dictionary objectForKey:@"myCustomClass"]
```